# One Producer, multiple Consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have been working on some code, but I need help. 
I have created one producer and one consumer, however I need to create multiple consumers who will consume the specific `String` from the producer e.g. I need a consumer that will consume specifically 'Move Left Hand'.

Contained in the code is the buffer, producer, consumer and the main. I am not sure how to notify the correct consumer and compare the string that needs to be consumed. As it stands I only have one consumer.

```
public class iRobotBuffer {
    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized String take() {
        // Wait until message is
        // available.
        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = true;
        // Notify producer that
        // status has changed.
        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void put(String message) {
        // Wait until message has
        // been retrieved.
        while (!empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = false;
        // Store message.
        this.message = message;
        // Notify consumer that status
        // has changed.
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class iRobotConsumer implements Runnable {
    private iRobotBuffer robotBuffer;

    public iRobotConsumer(iRobotBuffer robotBuffer){
        this.robotBuffer = robotBuffer;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (String message = robotBuffer.take();
                ! message.equals("DONE");
                message = robotBuffer.take()) {
            System.out.format("MESSAGE RECEIVED: %s%n", message);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class iRobotProducer implements Runnable {
    private iRobotBuffer robotBuffer;
    private int number;

    public iRobotProducer(iRobotBuffer robotBuffer)
    {  
        this.robotBuffer = robotBuffer;
        //this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        String commandInstructions[] = {
                "Move Left Hand",
                "Move Right Hand",
                "Move Both Hands",
        };
        int no = commandInstructions.length;
        int randomNo;
        Random random = new Random();


        for (int i = 0;
                i < commandInstructions.length;
                i++) {
            randomNo =(int)(Math.random()*no);
            System.out.println(commandInstructions[randomNo]);

            robotBuffer.put(commandInstructions[i]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        robotBuffer.put("DONE");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class iRobot
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        iRobotBuffer robotBuffer = new iRobotBuffer();
        (new Thread(new iRobotProducer(robotBuffer))).start();
        (new Thread(new iRobotConsumer(robotBuffer))).start();

    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Thanks for the editing the text, any chance of a constructive answer?

Comment: What is a *correct consumer*?

Comment: Editing is just a matter of helping people read the code. That's not _unconstructive_.

Comment: What I mean by correct consumer, is a consumer that will consume one of the produced strings e.g. move left hand will be consumed by left hand consumer. That is where I am stuck at the moment

Comment: You have different strategies for that: either comsumers polling the producer, or the producer registers listeners for each message type and notifying the listeners itself, or a mix of the two.

Comment: How would I set that up? I am not sure how that works.

Comment: Why have you deleted all the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your iRobotBuffer class. It needs to be a queue to support multiple producer / consumers. I've provided the code for such a queue, but java already has an implementation (`BlockingDeque<E>`).

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {

    private final LinkedList<T> innerList = new LinkedList<>();
    private boolean isEmpty = true;

    public synchronized T take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isEmpty) {
            wait();
        }

        T element = innerList.removeFirst();
        isEmpty = innerList.size() == 0;
        return element;
    }

    public synchronized void put(T element) {
        isEmpty = false;
        innerList.addLast(element);
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! How would you then make sure the correct message goes to the relevant consumer?

Comment: Then you need routing. You need an additional class that takes a message, and put it into the right queue, dependending on criteria. In message queue systems, they usually route by topic. This might help you understand the theory behind it : http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/14/understanding-amqp-the-protocol-used-by-rabbitmq/

Comment: Thank you! Would you have any ideas how to set up routing by topic? The link is offline.

Comment: It's complicated. You would have multiple queues, and each subscribers poll from its queue. Each queues has a topic wildcard applied to it (Translates to: I'm a subscriber and messages of top1.top2.* interests me). When you send messages, you have a topic with it (top1.top2.mytopic). The message will be duplicated and routed to all of subscribers which listens for this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like 3 consumers, one for each *move* instruction. 
You can use an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) from the `java.util.concurrent` package, in place of the `iRobotBuffer` class. By the way, you can have a look at the other concurrent collections provided - one may sweet you better.

Then for the consumer, you can `peek()` at what is in the queue and test if it matches the requirements and then `poll()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have not worked with Concurrent systems, or multiple threads before, so this is very new to me. Could you show me in the code what you mean? I am not familiar with these packages at all.